# Loading the pages in new tab using google chrome cause style problems

Tags: html, css, wordpress, google-chrome

I've developed before a website and it was working with no issues , then now whenever you open any page in a new tab the style appear with some problems on google chrome but whenever i refresh the page it return to it's original style while when i open the page without new tab it loads perfectly , I've tried this on Firefox and it's working well when i open any page in new tab or even in the same page , so what's can be the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Delete site prefences, Browsing and downloading history, cookies, chache,offline website data, ETC. Then Try to open pages.

---

If this not sought out your problem then reset Google Crome. Guide here http://ccm.net/faq/6361-reset-your-browser-restore-your-browser-to-default-settings